# Wrap text around a div like in Word

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, word-wrap

I would like to have achieve the following:

I want a block-element (div/img) in the middle of the screen and it should be surrounded by text like this:

> [image]

I know this functionality exists e.g. in M$ Word. Is there a way to do this with Web technologies (HTML, CSS, JS) too?

The specifics are not as important for my use case, as I want to surround the image with a word-cloud, therefore I don't mind if the text to the left and right is actually in columns rather than in lines.

Comment: It is possible at least in the near future. There is an implementation of CSS (exclusions) but it's not been approved and is highly experimental. In fact, you have to specifically turn the option on in browsers even if they support it...which most don't.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm talking about. Is there a way to do this with JavaScript perhaps?

Comment: I would try to do it with a 3x3 grid using a table element, and put the image in the center cell.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a brute force solution, but might give you an idea.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
}

.text:after {
  content: "Lorem ipsum drbi posuert, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi posuere adipiscing odio non euismod. Maecenas mi nulla, pellentesque eu semper noLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi posuere adipiscing odio non euismod. Maecenas mi nulla, pellentesque eu semper noLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi posuere adipiscing odio non euismod. Maecenas mi nulla, pellentesque eu semper noLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi posuere adipiscing odio non euismod. Maecenas mi nulla, pellentesqu adipiscing odio non euismod. Maecenas mi nulla, pellentesque eu semper noLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi posuere adipiscing odio non euismod. Maecenas mi nulla, pellentesque eu semper noLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi posuere adipiscing odio non euismod. Maecenas mi nulla, pellentesque eu semper non";
}

.left, .right {
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 31%;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text"></div>
<div class="text left"></div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVAmG.gif">
<div class="text right"></div>
<div class="text"></div>
```

Comment: I like your imagination, and I realize this was just an example, but for everyone getting any ideas from this: you should *never* put content in a stylesheet like that.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to implement this solution myself after a long while of fiddling around. However, as my next requirement states that the text is variable, I can't statically split it up into these areas.

Currently I am working on an extension of your idea that counts the words in the text and does a rough four-way split, depending on the areas that are covered by the individual <div>s.
(use jQuery to calculate height & width, multiply for each div, use the values to do a split based on word-count)
would you reckon a split based on character-count would be better?

Comment: There is a technique for measuring text exactly. You basically render the string into an element this is off-screen or hidden (width:auto) and then ask the DOM  for its size. So you can get as precise as you want.